# How to read/verbalize lambda expressions? What is `(λx.λy).M`?

Tags: lambda-calculus, associativity

In lambda calculus, application is left associative. That is, if `M`, `N`, and `P` are expressions, then we parse `MNP`<sup>1</sup> as `(MN)P`. But if we want the "alternative" parsing, we can get it using parentheses/grouping: `M(NP)`.

Conversely, abstraction is right associative. That is, if `x` and `y` are variables, then we parse `λx.λy.M`<sup>2</sup> as `λx.(λy.M)`. Is there an "alternative" parsing to `λx.λy.M`? Does `(λx.λy).M` makes sense? If not, can you give an example of a valid "alternative" parsing of chained abstractions where parenthesis would have to be used to the get the "alternative" parsing?

---

<sup>1</sup> My understanding is that when we see two expressions next to each other as in `MN` there is an implied application operator between them which says *"apply `M` to `N`"* or more verbosely *"feed `N` as input to `M`"*. Is this correct? If so, a phrase like *"`M` something `N`"* is desirable so we can read lambda expressions left to right. Maybe *"`M` consumes `N`"*?

<sup>2</sup> In this case it looks like the dot (`.`) is acting as the abstraction operator. Is there a way to verbalize `λx.M` left to right? Something like "function (`λ`) taking `x` outputing (`.`) `M`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A term in the lambda calculus is either:

- A variable -- that is an identifier
- An application -- that is a pair of two terms
- A lambda abstraction -- that is a term depending on a chosen identifier

So concretely, a term is represented by a tree where leaves are always variables, binary nodes are applications, and unary nodes (indexed by an identifier) are lambda abstractions. For example:
$$\texttt{Lam}(x,\texttt{Lam}(y,M))$$ where $M$ may depend on $x,y$, or
$$\texttt{Lam}(y,\texttt{App}(\texttt{Lam}(x,\texttt{Var}(x)),\texttt{Var}(y))).$$

This means that $\lambda x. t$ is just a way of writing $\texttt{Lam}(x,t)$, and the dot has no semantic value.

---

But now let's consider an alternative way of representing terms. A term is now either:

- A variable -- that is an identifier
- An application -- that is a pair of two terms
- A lambda abstraction -- that is a term valued *function*

The key difference now is that a lambda abstraction is given by a lambda abstraction $ x\mapsto M$ **in the meta-language**, so we might as well write $x . M$ and the examples above are now:

$$\texttt{Lam}(x . \texttt{Lam}(y . M))$$
and
$$\texttt{Lam}(y.\texttt{App}(\texttt{Lam}(x . \texttt{Var}(x)), \texttt{Var}(y))).$$
So now, $\lambda x . t$ could be parsed $\lambda (x . t)$, where $x . t$ is a function $x \mapsto t$ in the meta language.

Furthermore, if $f$ is a function producing a term, it would also be valid to write
$\lambda f$, which in turn is equivalent to $\lambda (x\mapsto (f x))$, which we may write $\lambda(x.(f x))$ or $\lambda x. (f x)$.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to understand. *Lam(x, Lam(y, M))* is `λx.λy.M`. Do I have the following correct?: 1. If *M = Var(x)*, then the tree is: https://bit.ly/3B7zudA  2. If *M = Var(y)*, then the tree is: https://bit.ly/2XwHIy6  3. If *M = App(Var(x), Var(y))*, then the tree is: https://bit.ly/3GbsboU  4. If *M = Var(z)*, then the tree is: https://bit.ly/3m20JSA

Comment: again thanks. Would the tree for (,((,()),())) look like this: https://bit.ly/3E1cnmS, or more verbosely, but equivalent: https://bit.ly/2ZkGrep.

Comment: What is the significance of the meta language?

Comment: @joseville This is the right way to look at it: https://bit.ly/3m3lvRH. Again, the dot is just syntactic sugar, it is not a node in the tree. The reason the arrows shouldn't have $Var$ is that they are not indexed by variables, but by *identifiers*. The meta language is the language of discourse, ie. that you use when doing mathematics.

Comment: @joseville Looking back at your diagrams, I think you may be confusing the [parse (concrete syntax) tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) and [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). The trees I am referring to are abstract syntax trees. The parse tree is a verbatim representation of the symbols you write (hence the dot is significant), whereas this is abstracted away in the abstract syntax tree.

Comment: thanks. Is "(.()" missing the closing paren? In the notation (,((,()),())),  and  represent binary operations - the two operands are separated by comma (,) and  represents a unary operation. Furthermore, the first operand of  and the only operand of  must be a variable (or identifier?). Is there a distinction between variable and identifier? Is () the variable whilst  is the identifier (is  not considered a variable)?

Comment: The distinction between an identifier and a variable is that a variable is a term, and an identifier (or string) is not. So while $Lam$ is binary, the first argument is an identifier, not a term, so it behaves like a unary node on terms. Yes, $x$ is an identifier, while $Var(x)$ is the variable. For more consistency, https://bit.ly/3lYaiSt is more accurate because the circles are all terms.

Comment: Going from the first notation to the second (e.g. (.((.()),())) ), it looks like the only transformation is that the comma (,) in all ( , ) gets replaced with a dot (.). Both these notations are along the same line as prefix notation where the binary operator is written, followed by the two operands. The final notation (e.g. *y.((x.x)y)*) seems to mix prefix notation for abstractions (if  is considered the binary operator) and implicit infix notation for the applications (*MN* <=> (M, N)) .